# Some background images are not loading in webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm not an android developer, but I'm trying to create a simple app to run my website using Webview. But images which are in the background of something are not loading.
I've searched on the internet and seen many answers, nothing yet worked out for me.

My MainActivity.java code looks like this.

```
    package com.example.pizzahouse;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://pizzahousepro.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to test on Chrome by the same device. Is it working?

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly there.

Comment: check image urls http https

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. I added this piece of code, mywebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW); but now the app is slow.